# What general purpose connectors are used for GPIO data?

Tags: connector, standard, best-practice

Let's say I have a chassis housing a raspberry pi.

I have a second chassis with some neopixels. I want to connect these two chassis with two panel mount connectors and a cable. The cable would be sending the data from the rpi to the neopixels.

What sort of connector would you recommend I use? Something cheap, panel mount, and not universally used for anything else, ie, USB connector or 3.5 mm connector are both bad ideas for obvious reasons.

I don't want to use a ribbon cable either, please assume both chassis are "sealed".

Maybe some sort of DIN connector? What is the standard connector for GPIO type data?

Comment: I happen to like the [Hirose HR30 series](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/HR30?lang=en) of circular plastic connectors that have a push-pull locking mechanism. I invested in the correct crimping tool for the contacts, which made working with them a breeze.

Comment: My apologies, let me rework this question as per your instructions.

Answer (score 3):

I usually go with Standard DB style (D-shell) connectors available in 9, 15 or 25 pin types. It's easy to get pre-made cables in a variety of lengths. You can go shielded or unshielded. You can get short ribbon cables that adapt your board (typically 0.1" IDC) to a DB connector that can be mounted to the chassis and then use a pre-made cable to connect the two boxes. Very robust.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a *standard* connector / *standard* cable. When you design something, it must fullfill (predefined) specifications (voltage rating, current rating, signal integrity, etc). You pick a connector according to those specs.

Although you haven't defined specs, maybe searching the web for "subminiature connector" (D-SUB) or "circular connector" may help you find something "cheap, panel mount".
Make sure it does fit the ratings of your spec